# bitmap image, gr.drawRectangle during mouse move event vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

When coding this:

```
Sub PcbOriginalMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Try
            If isSelecting = True Then
                x1 = e.X
                y1 = e.Y
                Dim bm As New Bitmap(pcbOriginal.Image)

                Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
                    gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Math.Min(x0,x1), Math.Min (y0,y1), Math.Abs(x0-x1), Math.Abs(y0-y1))
                End Using

                pcbOriginal.Image = bm
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception 
        End Try 
End Sub
```

I got a repeated rectangle (selected area when mouse move) seen in the pic:

**Mouse moved quickly:**

[image: drawn rectangle when moving the mouse quickly]

**Mouse moved slowly:**

[image: drawn rectangle when moving the mouse slowly]

Comment: So what's your question? What result do you expect?

Comment: I tried improving this question by editing it, but saw... You didn't even ask a question.

Comment: Oh, sorry! You absolutely right... My question is?

Comment: So sorry, you totally right. My question is, what should I do to get a simple selection rectangle?

Comment: I'm trying to select a picture area to copy it to another pictureBox. It should be quite ease, but ... thaks!

Comment: You should not be drawing on the `Image`. That makes it permanent. You should be drawing on the control in its `Paint` event handler. Each time a `Paint` event is raised, previous drawing is erased, allowing you to replace instead of add.

Comment: Right, New Bitmap() was a nice try but it uses the wrong bitmap.  The modified one, not the original.  Just store the original in a variable so you always start with a fresh copy.  This code should crash pretty quickly on OOM, disposing the old bitmap is not optional.

Comment: I suggest that you try the example provided for the [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help and answers.

Comment: Finally, it's working. I keep using New Bitmap(), but with a copy of the original image, as -jmcilhinney suggested me.

Comment: This is how it works! thanks again!

Comment: Try
   
   If isSelecting = True Then
    
    x1 = e.X
    y1 = e.Y
    
    originalImage =  Image.FromFile("D:\Imagenes\Logos\Logo-Tecnicos-para-Chile.jpg")
    
    Dim bm As New Bitmap (originalImage)
    
    Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
     
     gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Math.Min(x0,x1), Math.Min (y0,y1), Math.Abs(x0-x1), Math.Abs(y0-y1))
     
    End Using
    
    originalImage = bm 
    pcbOriginal.Image = originalImage
   End If
   
  Catch ex As Exception 
  End Try

Answer (score 0):

This is how is working:

Try

```
        If isSelecting = True Then

            x1 = e.X
            y1 = e.Y

            originalImage =  Image.FromFile("D:\Imagenes\Logos\Logo-Tecnicos-para-Chile.jpg")

            Dim bm As New Bitmap (originalImage)

            Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

                gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Math.Min(x0,x1), Math.Min (y0,y1), Math.Abs(x0-x1), Math.Abs(y0-y1))

            End Using

            originalImage = bm 
            pcbOriginal.Image = originalImage
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception 
    End Try[enter image description here][1]
```

The result: the user selects a pic area which is shown in another picbox[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihLXg.png